# Displaying a list of videos from a channel - Vimeo Advanced API

Tags: php, vimeo

I need a way to display videos from a specific channel on a page using PHP.

I have authenticated my app and I can use some methods using the advanced API. I am using the official vimeo PHP library to connect.

Below is what I am trying to do and when I dump the array I do not get anything. I can get info back from using get videos from the entire account method.

```
require_once('/url/vimeo/vimeo.php');
$vimeo = new phpVimeo('number', 'number');
$vimeo->setToken('number','numbers');

$videos = $vimeo->call('vimeo.channels.getVideos', array('ACCOUNT' => 'NAME'));
```

If I put the channel name where ACCOUNT is I will get an invalid signature error.

Is it worth using something like simple HTML parser for PHP and doing it that or worth sticking with the advanced API?

Comment: Just a suggestion, you can also directly use a plugin like Youmax to display videos from any Vimeo channel or User. Cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly advise using the advanced api. If you parse the html, it will break any time vimeo changes their channel pages. Additionally, channels have more than one layout

eg: [vimeohq](https://vimeo.com/channels/vimeohq) and [nicetype](https://vimeo.com/channels/nicetype)

The second parameter of the "call" function should be any querystring parameters the api method requires.

In the case of "vimeo.channels.getVideos" you can provide

- channel_id
- user_id
- page
- per_page
- summary_response
- full_response.

To experiment with the getVideos method, you can use the [playground](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods/vimeo.channels.getVideos/playground).

So in the end, I believe you want the function to look like this..

```
$videos = $vimeo->call('vimeo.channels.getVideos', array('channel_id' => 'NAME'));
```

where NAME is either the channel id, or the channel name (the channel name matches the url slug, so for example "nicetype" not "nice type"