# Vimeo API 2016 how to display list of users videos

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm having trouble finding a simplified tutorial for using the Vimeo API I know I need to include vimeo.php and the following

```
include 'vimeo.php';

$vimeo = new phpVimeo('Client Identifier', 'Client Secrets');
$videos = $vimeo->call('vimeo.videos.getUploaded', array('user_id' => "user1877648"));

print_r($videos);
```

I've copied and pasted the fields I've used from the access Authentication in case that's where the issue is, I've also read that for simple calls to the API don't need access tokens?

I could really do with some pointers as to how I get a list of vimeo thumbs linking to the vimeo url from a specific user? I was using the older code  and up until recently it worked well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086140/displaying-a-list-of-videos-from-a-channel-vimeo-advanced-api

Comment: Thanks that's the one I saw before - there is no actual tutorial for this and I can't get it working

Comment: Can you please explain in details what you need in exact. sorry i cannot understand

Comment: I need a list of vimeo thumbnails linking to the vimeo url - It was very easily set up before but now with the new API I am a little lost

Answer (score 3):

Dashron pointed you to all of the correct places to find the documentation needed to do what you are trying to do.

However, here is an example of how you would do it.

You need to download / clone the Vimeo PHP Library (found here: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php).

Then go to Vimeo and create an app so you can acquire a client id and client secret (https://developer.vimeo.com/api/start).

Now that you have a client id, client secret, and the vimeo library, you can create a simple script to load all of the videos from a specific user. Here is an example:

```
<?php

// include the autoload file from the vimeo php library that was downloaded
include __DIR__ . '/vimeo/autoload.php';

// The client id and client secret needed to use the vimeo API
$clientId = "";
$clientSecret = "";

// when getting an auth token we need to provide the scope
// all possible scopes can be found here https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#supported-scopes
$scope = "public";

// The id of the user
$userId = "alexbohs";

// initialize the vimeo library
$lib = new \Vimeo\Vimeo($clientId, $clientSecret);

// request an auth token (needed for all requests to the Vimeo API)
$token = $lib->clientCredentials($scope);

// set the token
$lib->setToken($token['body']['access_token']);

// request all of a user's videos, 50 per page
// a complete list of all endpoints can be found here https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints
$videos = $lib->request("/users/$userId/videos", ['per_page' => 50]);

// loop through each video from the user
foreach($videos['body']['data'] as $video) {

    // get the link to the video
    $link = $video['link'];

    // get the largest picture "thumb"
    $pictures = $video['pictures']['sizes'];
    $largestPicture = $pictures[count($pictures) - 1]['link'];
}
```

Keep in mind that the vimeo API returns "pages" of videos. So if the user has more than 50 videos per page you would need to do a request for each page by specifying the page number using "page" parameter (Change `['per_page' => 50]` to `['per_page' => 50, 'page' => #]`.

Comment: Thanks so much for this I really appreciate it, i've downloaded the entire vimeo.php-master folder and uploaded it to the wordpress theme - I've then copied your code and changed include __DIR__ . '/vimeo/autoload.php'; to include get_template_directory().'/vimeo/autoload.php';
but it's not working - sorry I'm lost now, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you honerlawd. Everything works great. BTW, you can test and familiarize yourself with the structure of the equired JSON data on the Vimeo Playground, here:  https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/users

Comment: People like you make my day putting stuff like this out to share! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the old, Advanced API. It is deprecated.

The new PHP library is here: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php

The new API docs are here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api

The endpoint to retrieve all of your videos is https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos (https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/me#/videos)

Comment: Thanks for this I really appreciate it, I haven't been able to find a working of example of setup and call - would you be able to help me out please? I only want a list of user videos in an unordered list - this was easy before

Comment: We're working on a getting started guide describing this very thing. I'll see if I can get something together, but this might be a good starting point: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php/blob/master/example/search.php#L33. Replace /videos with /me/videos, and instead of print_r, loop through the body and echo out the value of $video['embed']['html'].